# Sort available carriers based on cart products

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need to implement a simple functionnality to my Prestashop (v1.6.1.0):

Based on the cart content (product references) I need to sort carriers that will be available for the user on the 4th "shipping" page/tab.

As an example: I have 3 carriers, but one of theme has to be removed only if one of the cart's product reference starts with a 1 (it means it's fresh food and can't be shipped via this carrier).

How can I do that?

Comment: This is not a support website or a KB for Prestashop, but a developers community. What have you tried so far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Override function `getAvailableCarrierList` from `Carrier` class.

Edit the final loop:

```
if ($product->width > 0 || $product->height > 0 || $product->depth > 0 || $product->weight > 0)
{
    foreach ($carrier_list as $key => $id_carrier)
    {
        $carrier = new Carrier($id_carrier);

        // Get the sizes of the carrier and the product and sort them to check if the carrier can take the product.
        $carrier_sizes = array((int)$carrier->max_width, (int)$carrier->max_height, (int)$carrier->max_depth);
        $product_sizes = array((int)$product->width, (int)$product->height, (int)$product->depth);
        rsort($carrier_sizes, SORT_NUMERIC);
        rsort($product_sizes, SORT_NUMERIC);

        if (($carrier_sizes[0] > 0 && $carrier_sizes[0] < $product_sizes[0])
            || ($carrier_sizes[1] > 0 && $carrier_sizes[1] < $product_sizes[1])
            || ($carrier_sizes[2] > 0 && $carrier_sizes[2] < $product_sizes[2]))
        {
            $error[$carrier->id] = Carrier::SHIPPING_SIZE_EXCEPTION;
            unset($carrier_list[$key]);
        }

        if ($carrier->max_weight > 0 && $carrier->max_weight < $product->weight * $cart_quantity)
        {
            $error[$carrier->id] = Carrier::SHIPPING_WEIGHT_EXCEPTION;
            unset($carrier_list[$key]);
        }


        //Here goes the magic
        foreach ($cart->getProducts(false, $product->id) as $cart_product) {
            $aProduct = new Product($cart_product['id_product']);
            if (substr($aProduct->reference, 0, 1) == 1) {
                unset($carrier_list[$key]);
            }
        }


    }
}

return $carrier_list;
```

Still better, no need to override whole function:

```
public static function getAvailableCarrierList(Product $product, $id_warehouse, $id_address_delivery = null, $id_shop = null, $cart = null, &$error = array())
{
    $carrier_list = parent::getAvailableCarrierList($product, $id_warehouse, $id_address_delivery, $id_shop, $cart, &$error);

    if (is_null($cart))
        $cart = Context::getContext()->cart;

    if ($product->width > 0 || $product->height > 0 || $product->depth > 0 || $product->weight > 0)
    {
        foreach ($carrier_list as $key => $id_carrier)
        {
            //Here goes the magic
            foreach ($cart->getProducts(false, $product->id) as $cart_product) {
                $aProduct = new Product($cart_product['id_product']);
                if (substr($aProduct->reference, 0, 1) == 1) {
                    unset($carrier_list[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $carrier_list;
}
```

Untested.